# How to update radio button checked status with keyboard in real time JS

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an accordion with invisible radio buttons. Everything works fine and well, until I try to get the status of the radio button. I have 4 rows of the following code for each accordion radio button:

```js
const ac1 = document.getElementById('ac-1');
```

Radio buttons wrapped in a form:

```html
<form class="ac-container">
<input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="radio" checked="checked">
<input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="radio">
<input id="ac-3" name="accordion-1" type="radio">
<input id="ac-4" name="accordion-1" type="radio">
</form>
```

And this is my radio button CSS:

```css
.ac-container input {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

To check the status of the radio button I've tried:

```js
if (ac1.checked) {
  //do something
} 

if (document.getElementById('ac-1').checked) {
  //do something
}
```

I need the radio button status so I can display stuff in real time. For regular clicks I'm just using `addEventListener('click', (e) => {}` and it works fine, but I need the radio buttons to also function with keyboard. That's why I need the status, so if a radio button is checked I can immediately update what's needed.

I'm not sure if this is the problem but, when I click on the radio buttons, the 'checked' attribute never transfers from one button to the other?

I'll keep looking and update if I find anything.

Comment: Might a `change` or `keydown` event work?

Comment: `change` actually looks promising, I'll give it a try first thing tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Since the OP uses checkbox and/or radio controls why does the OP then need a JavaScript based solution? (Almost) everything could be achieved by pure HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for `input` event.

Example:

```html
<input type="radio" name="value" id="inp">
<input type="radio" name="value" id="inp2">
<script>

const inp = document.getElementById("inp")
const inp2 = document.getElementById("inp2")

inp.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    console.log(inp.checked)
})

inp2.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    console.log(inp.checked)
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my above comment ...

> *"Since the OP uses checkbox and/or radio controls why does the OP then need a JavaScript based solution? (Almost) everything could be achieved by pure HTML/CSS. "*

```css
[data-accordion] [type="radio"] + p,
[data-accordion] [type="checkbox"] + p {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2.5s ease-out;
  
}
[data-accordion] [type="radio"]:checked + p,
[data-accordion] [type="checkbox"]:checked + p {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
h2 { margin: 0; font-size: 1em; }
p { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<article data-accordion>
  <section>
    <h2>Topic 4</h2>
    <input type="radio" name="single-fold" />
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nec lectus ante. Suspendisse sed tortor purus. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc pharetra odio id lorem pellentesque tincidunt.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Topic 5</h2>
    <input type="radio" name="single-fold" />
    <p>
      Praesent ut ipsum efficitur, commodo lectus eu, maximus risus. Fusce eu ipsum mauris. Pellentesque semper neque a convallis consequat. Suspendisse eu urna quis est condimentum dapibus id ac lectus. Nulla sit amet hendrerit arcu.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
  <h2>Topic 6</h2>
  <input type="radio" name="single-fold" />
  <p>
    Vestibulum vel sapien convallis diam iaculis consectetur non non ex. Suspendisse eget hendrerit ipsum. Suspendisse finibus quam eget est fringilla, finibus vehicula tortor varius. Praesent fermentum ac odio a ullamcorper.
    </p>
  </section>
</article>

<hr/>

<article data-accordion>
  <section>
    <h2>Topic 1</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nec lectus ante. Suspendisse sed tortor purus. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc pharetra odio id lorem pellentesque tincidunt.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Topic 5</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <p>
      Praesent ut ipsum efficitur, commodo lectus eu, maximus risus. Fusce eu ipsum mauris. Pellentesque semper neque a convallis consequat. Suspendisse eu urna quis est condimentum dapibus id ac lectus. Nulla sit amet hendrerit arcu.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section>
  <h2>Topic 3</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  <p>
    Vestibulum vel sapien convallis diam iaculis consectetur non non ex. Suspendisse eget hendrerit ipsum. Suspendisse finibus quam eget est fringilla, finibus vehicula tortor varius. Praesent fermentum ac odio a ullamcorper.
    </p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: I need it in JS because I render map routes based on which radio button is checked, if I only did it HTML/CSS I would have no way of knowing which radio button corresponds to which rendered map route, therefore not being able to render the correct map route.